# Public method in jquery plugin not working

Tags: jquery, plugins

I have written the following plugin using JQuery but I can't get the public method to fire. Instead, I get a message in the console saying:

> "TypeError: $(...).panIt.doSomething is not a function".

My plugin code is as follows:

```
;(function() {

// custom panel class
$.fn.panIt = function(options) {

    var def = $.Deferred();
    var pan;

    var defaults = {
        container:        '<div class="panel_plugin"></div>',
        url:            '../../../js/plugins/myPanel/plugin.php',
        padding:        true,
        header:         {
                            isHeadline: false,
                            title:      null,
                            subTitle:   null,
                            minPanel: {
                                isAJAX:     false,
                                content:    ''
                            }
                        },
        footer:         false,
        body:        {
                            isAJAX:     false,
                            content:    ''
                        },
        allowScrolling: true,
        button:         {
                            toggle: true,
                            remove: true
                        },
        index:          null,
        panelSize:      'small',
        parent:         null, 
        domID:          null,
        buttons:       {
                        close: true,
                        sizeUp: true
        },
        onLoaded:       $.noop
    };

    var settings =  $.extend(true, defaults, options); // extend (i.e. merge) defaults with options passed across when plugin is invoked

    var deferredList = [];

    this.doSomething= function() { alert("coey"); };

    //Apply to each instance of the plugin
    this.each(function() {

        var innerDef = $.Deferred();
        addContainer(this);
        updateSettings(this);
        pan =  $(this).find("div.panel_plugin"); // reference for this plugin

        $.when ( loadPluginContent() ).done(function(result) {
            if(result === "success") {
                applySettings();
                setupPanEvents();
                console.log("Plugin html successfully loaded for index " + settings.index); // get count of stats plugins loaded on the page
                innerDef.resolve();
            } else {
                alert ("There was an error loading the plugin content for " + settings.index);
            } 
        });

        deferredList.push(innerDef.promise());
    });


    $.when.apply($, deferredList).done(function() {
        def.resolve("All of my inner defs have been resolved"); 
    });

    return def.promise();

};

}) (jQuery);
```

And when I invoke my plugin I use this:

```
$('#total_membership').panIt({
        header:         {
                            title:      'Total Membership',
                            minPanel: {
                                isAJAX:     false,
                                content:    '<div class="panel-subtitle"> 12800</p>'
                            }
                        },
        body:           {
                            isAJAX: true,
                            content: 'membership_total.php'
        }
    });
```

And then a bit later I use this code to try and call the public method:

```
$('#total_membership').panIt.doSomething();
```

The plugin works fine if I omit this last line of code (but obviously I then can't use my public method).

I am pretty new to JQuery plugins and I appreciate that there are a lot of different boilerpates out there but is anybody able to advise me where I am going wrong? Much apprecaited.

Comment: Do you ever initialize the plugin?

Comment: No I don't.  The template I took my code from didn't have any initialization function. How do I do that?

Comment: By the way, a plugin should return the same object collection so it can be chained with other jQuery functions or plugins.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I initialize it in my first bit of code. The plugin effectively creates a nice panel object with a header and content, etc. Once the plugin is loaded there are certain methods I then want to invoke

Comment: So how would I return a promise AND the same object?

Comment: You can’t. You should store the instance and then retrieve it to call the method for that instance.

Comment: Ok well I tried commenting out the Promise line of code and returning this.each but the method still doesn't work and I still get the same error.

Comment: It could be something to do with the order in which you are including the JavaScript files.  Try loading them in a different order, or loading them at the bottom of the HTML file instead of the top.

Comment: Thanks but the plugin works ok if I don't include the method so that makes me think that it doesn't have anything to do with the order of the files

Comment: @jmb.mage No, it has nothing to do with the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a basic snippet/idea on how to create a custom plugin, to be able to access methods later. I added inline comments for clarification.

With this example, first initialization will take the first argument as options for the object. The latter calls, will take the first argument as a method name, and the rest of the argument, as arguments for the method.

**Edit**

It also defines the plugin defaults in to a modifiable public object, so the plugin defaults can be overwritten anytime.

Two methods are defined, a `chainable` that can be used with the basic method call: `$(selector).customPlugin('method', [arguments])` and a `nonChainable` method (like a static method, it won't have access to the jQuery selected elements but can perform any other basic usage.

So, if you need to use the elements in within the method, you need to use the first approach. If the methods are just helpers and won't use the plugin dom elements defined in the selection query, you can use the second approach.

Hope it helps.

```js
$(function() {
 
 // Create custom plugin
 $.fn.customPlugin = function() {
  
  // Transforms the arguments to an array
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  
  // If the method is defined
  if($.fn.customPlugin.hasOwnProperty(args[0])) {
   
   // Execute the method, passed in first argument
   return $.fn.customPlugin[args[0]].apply(this, args.slice(1));
   
  } else {
   
   // Return all the matched elements so the function can be chained
   return this.each(function() {
    
    // If the plugin has not been initialized for the object
    if(typeof this.customStorage === 'undefined') {
     
     console.log('initialized');
     
     // Set data storage for the current element
     // This will allow to do any data storage for the element, and it will allow to check if the plugin has been initialized for the element
     this.customStorage = {};
     
     // Define custom options
     this.customStorage.options = $.extend(true, {}, $.fn.customPlugin.defaults, args[0]);
     
     // Do all your initialization sfuff...
     
    }
    
   });
   
  }
  
 };
 
 // Default options for the plugin
 $.fn.customPlugin.defaults = {
  message : 'default!'
 };
 
 // Chainable method, invoked by calling the main plugin method
 $.fn.customPlugin.chainable = function(message) {
  
  // If the method can be chained (applied to a jQuery element query)
  if(typeof this.each === 'undefined') throw { message : 'This method is chainable only' };
  
  // Return all the matched elements so the function can be chained
  return this.each(function() {
   
   // If the plugin has not been initialized for the object
   if(typeof this.customStorage === 'undefined') throw { message : 'You must initialize the plugin for the object to apply plugin methods to it' };
   
   $.fn.customPlugin.notChainable(this.customStorage.options.message, message);
   
  });
 };
 
 // Not chainable method
 $.fn.customPlugin.notChainable = function(messages) {
  
  // Can apply any action, but it does not have access to the elements of the jQuery element query
  
  console.log.apply(console, arguments);
  
 };
 
 // Initilizes the plugin
 $('#foo').customPlugin();
 
 // Initializes the option with a custom message
 $('#bar').customPlugin({ message : 'custom!' });
 
 // Then, later, call the custom method 'foo' with different arguments for each instance
 $('#foo').customPlugin('chainable', 'Message to log...');
 
 // Try to use a chaniable method by chaining
 try {
  $('#bar').customPlugin.chainable('Another message to log...');
 } catch(error) {
  console.log('Error!:', error.message);
 }
 
 //
 $('#bar').customPlugin.notChainable('A simple message to log...');
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo"></div>
<div id="bar"></div>
```

Comment: Many thanks again, muecas. Please can you advise what "this.customStorage" refers to? Is this to do with somekind of data storage? Where should I read up on this? Thanks again.Also, one other question: is there anyway of writing this so that the method is invoked in the following way: myplugin.method()   ?

Comment: @LeeA `customStorage` is to do any kind of object storage, and to check if the plugin has been initialized for the given element. It could be anything, any kind of value (data torage, class) or whatever it will tell the function execution that the plugin has been initialized for the element. And no, you will not be able to call `plugin.method()`. The method must be executed in an element scope, so you need to tell the plugin on which element you want to execute the method. Thats why it must be called in within an element: `$('myelement').plugin('method');` to apply `method`, to `myelement`.

Comment: @LeeA just curious, why you want to call the method that way?

Comment: Thanks again *muecas. My only reason for wanting to call it that way is because that's how some of the other '3rd party' plugins I am using do it. But your way makes sense. Thanks again.

Comment: @LeeA well you could do it that way, but you will need a more complex plugin structure.

Comment: Thanks @muecas. 'Simple' is better for me at this stage!:)

Comment: @LeeA does it solved you problem? Feedback appreciated! :)

Comment: Thanks @muecas. Yep that has answered the question for me. I clearly need to keep researching and learning but your code provides a good solution for me - so thanks.

Comment: @LeeA great!!, tick it if it provided a solution :)

Comment: I was doing some more research today and found an article which advises on using the fn object to add public methods and properties: https://gabrieleromanato.name/jquery-add-public-properties-and-methods-to-plugins-using-the-fn-object @meucas, is one way better than the other?

Comment: @LeeA I didn’t thought about it in that way. Let me modify it to use the proposed pattern from the article.

Comment: @LeeA there it goes. You custom plugin fitting your needs :-)

Comment: Thanks again, @meucas. Just want to check my understanding. You return self.each but console.log(this...). Could I use self or this in both cases? Also, is there a reason for keeping with the original method you provided (as opposed to this new method)? I read somewhere about not pulltign the JQuery namespace but I don't really know what that means! :)

Comment: @LeeA let me check my last edit. I want to do some edits on it. And explain some things.

Comment: @LeeA Hey! I added a bunch of improvements. I've been testing and researching. Read the edit, and the inline commets as well. This is the bes approach the jQuery plugin interface can offer fot methods. Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response @muecas. Was a big help so just wanted to say thanks again